# Saving graphic to EEPROM, compressing graphic by filter repeating 0x00 and 0xFF to save space

Tags: c++, c, compression, avr, eeprom

As part of firmware, I want to save a graphic or graphics into the EEPROM of a MCU. The space is not much, 1K, however it can save some program space. And yes you can seperate the glyphs of the graphic to save space however it is not easy to manage and you need more code to display it right.

Most of the monochrome GUI graphics do not fill the screen entirely and contain allot of empty space or repeating pixels. The images are already compressed, each bit in a byte represent 8 pixels.

I show the graphics on a tiny display of 128x32 pixels. Display it and erase the parts that are not relevant, works perfectly fine and efficient.

So I came up with the idea to filter those repeats, to compress it a little. With success, a bitmap like this (see below), is 496 bytes and 'compressed' with my method less 401 bytes.

---

[image]

---

That doesn't sound much however is a 20% decrease in total size, really great when there is only 1K storage available.

Example of byte array:

```
PROGMEM const uint8_t TEP_DISPLAY [] = { /* 496 bytes */
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x06, 0x00, 0x80, 0x90, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x01, 0x80, 0x03, 0xC0, 0x01, 0x80, 0x00, 0x47, 0x0F, 0xFE,
0x17, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x90, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x60, 0x01, 0x80, 0x01, 0x87, 0x10, 0x02,
0x30, 0x83, 0xE3, 0xFC, 0x00, 0x61, 0xE7, 0x39, 0xB6, 0x6F, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x03, 0x07, 0x36, 0xDA,
0x7F, 0xF0, 0x83, 0xFC, 0x7C, 0x7D, 0xB3, 0x6D, 0xB6, 0x61, 0x9B, 0x1F, 0x03, 0x87, 0x36, 0xDA,
0x30, 0x43, 0xE1, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x61, 0xB3, 0x6D, 0xA7, 0xCF, 0xB3, 0x00, 0x01, 0x80, 0x36, 0xDA,
0x13, 0x81, 0xC0, 0x60, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x66, 0x6D, 0xCC, 0x1B, 0x36, 0x00, 0x01, 0x07, 0x10, 0x02,
0x03, 0x00, 0x80, 0x60, 0x00, 0xFB, 0x66, 0x39, 0x8C, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x02, 0x07, 0x0F, 0xFE,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x01, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1C, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x2A, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xA2, 0xD5, 0x54,
0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x02,
0x00, 0xC0, 0x22, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x02, 0x20, 0x00, 0x82, 0x48, 0x20, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00,
0x40, 0xC0, 0x01, 0xE0, 0x00, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x01, 0x50, 0x00, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x02,
0x00, 0xC0, 0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x07, 0xC2, 0x01, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x21, 0x01, 0x08, 0x0E, 0x00,
0x4F, 0xFC, 0x00, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x40, 0x3F, 0xF8, 0x03, 0xF8, 0x03, 0x01, 0x80, 0x0B, 0x02,
0x1C, 0xC2, 0x21, 0x11, 0x08, 0x1C, 0x42, 0x40, 0x04, 0x84, 0x04, 0x21, 0x11, 0x08, 0x69, 0x80,
0x59, 0xE2, 0x01, 0x11, 0x00, 0x18, 0x40, 0x55, 0x54, 0x05, 0x54, 0x03, 0x39, 0x80, 0x3B, 0x02,
0x12, 0xD2, 0x21, 0x11, 0x08, 0x10, 0x42, 0x40, 0x04, 0x84, 0x04, 0x21, 0x7D, 0x08, 0x1E, 0x00,
0x54, 0xCA, 0x01, 0x83, 0x00, 0x10, 0x40, 0x55, 0x54, 0x05, 0x54, 0x03, 0x11, 0x80, 0x3E, 0x02,
0x12, 0x12, 0x21, 0x01, 0x08, 0x11, 0xC2, 0x40, 0x04, 0x84, 0x04, 0x21, 0x11, 0x08, 0x6B, 0x00,
0x51, 0xE2, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x13, 0xC0, 0x47, 0xC4, 0x04, 0x44, 0x01, 0x11, 0x00, 0x09, 0x82,
0x10, 0x02, 0x21, 0x01, 0x08, 0x71, 0x82, 0x40, 0x04, 0x84, 0x04, 0x23, 0x01, 0x88, 0x0B, 0x00,
0x4F, 0xFC, 0x01, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x00, 0x3F, 0xF8, 0x05, 0x54, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x02,
0x0F, 0xFC, 0x20, 0xFE, 0x08, 0x60, 0x02, 0x1F, 0xF0, 0x84, 0x04, 0x20, 0xFE, 0x08, 0x0C, 0x00,
0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02
};
```

---

Still there is one problem and I think it is a small error in code and I cannot detect it (because spend a couple days on it to think about how to get it some smaller). Maybe there is somebody that can point me into the right direction to solve the problem.

**The problem**

The problem occurs when there are allot of similarties, more than 255 repetitions of the same, such as many 0xFF repeating lines or 0x00 repeating empty spaces. In my code I take some precautions to avoid a byte overflow however it fails (and now cannot figure out why). What I try to do is when there is an overflow, record it and start allover again with counting. I cannot figure out it is a problem of the read function or just the write function.

**This is the layout of storage**

```
At start address:
-----------------
<byte width>
<byte heigth>
<uint16 dataSize>
<data>
  <if data=0xFF>
    <0xFF>
    <repeat count>
   </if>
   <if data=0x00>
     <0x00>
     <repeat count>
   </if>
 <else data>
</data>
```

**Here is my code:**

```
uint16_t TOLEDdisplay::writeToEeprom( uint16_t iAddress )
{
  if( width == 0 || height == 0 || cacheSize == 0 )
   { return 0; }

  uint8_t   iZeros    = 0;
  uint8_t   iFFs      = 0;
  bool      bIsZero   = false;  
  bool      bIsFF     = false;
  bool      bZeroOverflow = false;
  bool      bFFOverflow = false;

  uint16_t  iBits     = 0;
  uint8_t*  pByteSize = (uint8_t*)&iBits;
  uint8_t   iZeroCount = 0; // empty stripes , same pixels in a row
  uint8_t   iFFCount   = 0; // filled stripes, same pixels in a row 


  // Write screen bounds, when read it back with readFromEeprom,
  // this bounds must match with the current screen bounds.
  EEPROM.write( iAddress++, width );
  EEPROM.write( iAddress++, height );

   // Reserve two bytes for stream size
  uint16_t iSizeAddress = iAddress++;
  ++iAddress;

   // Write the cache content to the EEPROM
  uint16_t  i = 0;
  while( i < cacheSize )
  {
    iBits   = getCacheRawBits( i );
    //iBits   = displayCache[ i ];
    bIsFF   = ( iBits == 0xFF );
    bIsZero = ( iBits == 0x00 ); 

    if( bIsFF && !bFFOverflow )
     { ++iFFs; } 
    bFFOverflow = (iFFs == 0xFF);

    if( bIsZero && !bZeroOverflow )
     { ++iZeros; }
    bZeroOverflow = (iZeros == 0xFF);

    if( (!bIsFF && !bIsZero) || bFFOverflow || bZeroOverflow )
    {
           if( (!bIsFF && iFFs > 0) || bFFOverflow )
           { 
              // Read function knows if there is a 0xFF, amount of 0xFF
              // will be follow.
             EEPROM.write( iAddress++, 0xFF ); 
              // Write the amount of FF's
             EEPROM.write( iAddress++, iFFs ); 

             iFFCount+=iFFs;

              // If there is no byte 'overflow' iFFs = 0, otherwise it is 1
             iFFs = (uint8_t)bIsFF;
           }  

           if( (!bIsZero && iZeros > 0) || bZeroOverflow )
           { 
              // Read function knows if there is a zero, amount of zeros
              // will be follow.
             EEPROM.write( iAddress++, 0 ); 
              // Write the amount of zero's
             EEPROM.write( iAddress++, iZeros ); 

             iZeroCount+=iZeros;

              // If there is no byte 'overflow' iZeros = 0, otherwise it is 1
             iZeros = (uint8_t)bIsZero;
           }  

            // Avoid confusion writing a FF or zero 
           if( !bIsFF && !bIsZero  )           
            { EEPROM.write( iAddress++, iBits ); }
    }

    ++i;
  }

   // Calculate stream size
  iBits=iAddress-iSizeAddress-1;

   // Write size of stream
  EEPROM.write( iSizeAddress  , *pByteSize++ );
  EEPROM.write( iSizeAddress+1, *pByteSize );

  Serial.print( "Zeros found: " );
  Serial.println( iZeroCount );
  Serial.print( "FF found: " );
  Serial.println( iFFCount );
  Serial.print( "SIZE: " );
  Serial.println( iBits );

  // return bytes written
  return iBits+2;
}

bool TOLEDdisplay::readFromEeprom( uint16_t iAddress )
{
  uint8_t  bits    = 0;
  uint16_t i       = 0; 
  uint8_t* pI      = (uint8_t*)&i;
  uint8_t  iZeros  = 0;
  uint8_t  iFFs    = 0;

  uint8_t  iWidth  = EEPROM.read( iAddress++ );
  uint8_t  iHeight = EEPROM.read( iAddress++ );

   // Read stream size, read two bytes
  *pI = EEPROM.read( iAddress++ );
  *pI++;
  *pI = EEPROM.read( iAddress++ );

   // Clear the screen
  clear();

  Serial.print( "Size: " );
  Serial.println( i );
  Serial.print( "Width: " );
  Serial.println( iWidth );
  Serial.print( "Height: " );
  Serial.println( iHeight );

   // If an error (no image on EEPROM address) or screen bounds 
   // doesn't match, skip to continue
  if( i == 0 || iWidth != width || iHeight != height )
  {  
    update( true );
    return false; 
  }

  uint16_t iCacheAddress = 0; 

  while( i-- )
  {
    do { 
     if( iFFs == 0 && iZeros == 0 )
     {
        bits = EEPROM.read( iAddress++ );    

        if( bits == 0xFF )
         { 
           // read amount of FF's minus this one
           iFFs = EEPROM.read( iAddress++ )-1; 
           Serial.print( "iFFs: ");
           Serial.println( iFFs );
         }
        else if( bits == 0x00 )
             { 
               // read amount of zeros minus this one
               iZeros = EEPROM.read( iAddress++ )-1; 
               Serial.print( "iZeros: ");
               Serial.println( iZeros );
             }
     }   
     else { 
            if( iFFs > 0 )
            {
              --iFFs; 
              bits = 0xFF;
            }
            else if( iZeros > 0 )
                 {
                   --iZeros; 
                   bits = 0x00;
                 }  
          }


      setCacheRawBits( iCacheAddress, bits );
      ++iCacheAddress;
    }
    while( iFFs == 0 && iZeros == 0 );
  }

  update( true );
  return true;
}
```

***Any ideas?***

---

***NOTE:***

*I don't want to use any expensive compression method, 96% of program space is already in use and my method seems to work fine but with some error and I need to know the error, no alternative compression method. It has some compression already, bits in a byte to represent 8 pixels and just want to slim it down a bit (proven however with error at byte overflow).*

Comment: Bad hairday guys? -1 explain why when you downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some sleep I redone it with much better results and less code, I overcomplicated such thing too much.

I got impressive results with it and think about to refine it with an examination method to find the best 'compression' by selecting the bytes that repeats the most and record this into the EEPROM 'file'.

Anyway, this is my code, much better comparing to the first one, maybe it can help others. It is very lightweight solution to save some bytes.

For example a blank screen or full filled screen with a resolution of 128x32 pixels results in only 9 bytes, half by half only 17 bytes. The screen I showed in the question before 'compiles' to only 405 bytes, a saving of about 100 bytes.

---

**Here is my renewed code:**

```
uint8_t TOLEDdisplay::getCacheRawBits( uint16_t iAddress )
{
  if( iAddress < cacheSize )
   { return displayCache[ iAddress ]; }

  return 0x00;
}

bool TOLEDdisplay::setCacheRawBits( uint16_t iAddress, uint8_t iBitByte )
{
  if( iAddress < cacheSize )
  { 
     displayCache[ iAddress ]=iBitByte; 
     return true;
  }

  return false;
}

uint16_t TOLEDdisplay::writeToEeprom( uint16_t iAddress )
{
  if( cacheSize == 0 || width == 0 || height == 0 )
   { return 0; }

  uint8_t   iBits;              // Pixel * 8 = byte
  uint8_t   iFoundBits;         // 'Type' of detected 
  uint16_t  iByteSize = 0;      // Total byte size of stream
  uint8_t   iCount    = 0;      // Count of repeats found 
  bool      bSame;              // Boolean to evaluate repeats   

  // Write screen bounds, when read it back with readFromEeprom,
  // these bounds need to match with current screen bounds.
  EEPROM.write( iAddress++, width );
  EEPROM.write( iAddress++, height );

   // Reserve two bytes for stream size
  uint16_t iSizeAddress = iAddress;
  iAddress+=2;

   // Write the cache content to the EEPROM
  uint16_t  i = 0;
  while( i < cacheSize )
  {
     // Get a byte with bits
    iBits = getCacheRawBits( i );
    ++i;

     // Find repeating lines or empty lines 
    if( iBits == 0xFF || iBits == 0x00 )
    {
      iFoundBits = iBits;  // Set found bits to detect changes
      bSame      = true;   // Set to true to able to start loop
      iCount=1;            // Count this found one

       // Loop to find duplicates
      while( bSame && ( iCount < 0xFF ) && ( i < cacheSize )) 
      { 
          iBits = getCacheRawBits( i );   // Get next byte with bits
          bSame = (iBits == iFoundBits);  // Determine is repeat, the same
          iCount+=bSame;                  // Increment count when same is found
          i+=bSame;
      }       

       // Finally write result to EEPROM
      EEPROM.write( iAddress++, iFoundBits ); // type
       // Write the amount 
      EEPROM.write( iAddress++, iCount ); // count

      // Goto main loop and find next if any 
    }
   else { 
           // Write found value normally to EEPROM
          EEPROM.write( iAddress++, iBits ); 
        } 
  }

  // Final EOF address is one pos back
  --iAddress; 

   // Calculate stream size
  iByteSize=iAddress-iSizeAddress;
  uint8_t*  pByteSize = (uint8_t*)&iByteSize;

   // Write size of stream
  EEPROM.write( iSizeAddress  , *pByteSize++ );
  EEPROM.write( iSizeAddress+1, *pByteSize );

  // return bytes written including width and height bytes (+2 bytes)
  return iByteSize+2;
}

bool TOLEDdisplay::readFromEeprom( uint16_t iAddress )
{
  uint8_t  iBits;
  uint8_t  iRepeats;   
  uint16_t i        = 0; 
  uint8_t* pI       = (uint8_t*)&i;

  uint8_t  iWidth  = EEPROM.read( iAddress++ );
  uint8_t  iHeight = EEPROM.read( iAddress++ );

   // Read stream size, read two bytes
  *pI = EEPROM.read( iAddress++ );
  *pI++;
  *pI = EEPROM.read( iAddress++ );

   // Clear the screen
  clear();

   // If an error (no image on EEPROM address) or screen bounds 
   // doesn't match, skip to continue
  if( i == 0 || iWidth != width || iHeight != height )
  {  

    update( true ); // Set screen to blank
    return false; 
  }

  uint16_t iCacheAddress = 0; 

  while( i-- )
  {
      // Get a byte with bits
     iBits = EEPROM.read( iAddress++ );    

      // Explode repeats if detected
     if( iBits == 0xFF || iBits == 0x00 )
     { 
        // read amount of repeats
       iRepeats = EEPROM.read( iAddress++ ); 

        // Explode it into cache
       while( iRepeats-- )
        { setCacheRawBits( iCacheAddress++, iBits ); }
     }   
     else { 
             // Put value normally into cache
            setCacheRawBits( iCacheAddress++, iBits ); 
          }
  }

   // Done, update the screen
  update( true );

   // Return success
  return true;
}
```

---

Maybe I have to add some EEPROM boundry checks but for now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The first time thru the loop, `bFFOverflow` and `bZeroOverflow` are accessed without having been initialized.

The main problem, though, is that after you record your 255 0 or 0xFF bytes, you set the count to 1 if there are more.  However, this should be zero, since you detect the overflow after you've counted the 255th copy of that byte.

So always set `bFFOverflow` and `bZeroOverflow` to 0 writing out the counts.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick answer. You are not right, the booleans are intialized before checking condition. And i believe you are also not right when it comes to count. When there is an overflow there is still one left if it was a one of both 0x00 or 0xFF conditions. However, take a look at it tommorow ;-) Thanks

Comment: just test it change the booleans in initialization part to false, doesn't make any sense.